# Building a gallery with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I am planning to make a gallery component, that uses the scrollview and image APIs.

How does the scrollview handle the child components when it scrolls down, does it unmount the not display parts? what does it do the other children?

What if you have more than 100 images, it will surely affect performance. Does react handle the caching and garbage collection? or do you have to implement your own?

I'd like to have tips regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) which is optimised for performance. You can specify when a row needs to re-rendered.

Moreover, there are existing gallery components like [this](https://github.com/halilb/react-native-photo-browser)